# How to weight result scores based on order and distance of words in phrase using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a query that searches for a phrase, how can I have Elasticsearch weight the scores based on the order and distance of each word in the phrase rather than their presence? For example, if I search for 'house to rent' I build the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "query_string": {
          "query": "house for rent"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

This query returns the results ordered like:

```
"I am looking to rent a house" -> all terms present out of order with words in between
"I am looking for a house that would be for me to rent" -> all terms present in order with words in between
"I am looking for house to rent" -> 'house for rent' exactly
"I live in a house" -> only 1 term present
```

The top 3 results contain all words in the phrase, but sometimes out of order or with words in between. I would expect the exact phrase match to have the highest score but it doesn't. How can I adjust the scoring to take into account the order and distance of the phrase? Can I achieve this with `query_string` or is there a different type of query I should use?